# Openlayers 3 + Use React to display vector features

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using openlayers in a React based JS app. I have a vector layer that has different colors according to a field given from the server.

Is it possible to use react for drawing the icons on the map? or should I use simple openlayers object with simple plain javascript?

Regards,
Ido